# Can you use auto with a comma

Tags: c++, initialization, auto

Can you use an `auto` deduced type where you have a comma to indicate initialization of two or more variables. Like this:

```
 auto p = c.begin(), e = c.end();
```

Or is the presence of two initializations  (potentially) too confusing for a compiler? What does the C++ standard allow?

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: `for (auto p = c.begin(), e = c.end(); p != e; ++p);` works just fine

Comment: `auto [p, e] = std::make_pair(c.begin(), c.end());` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 `auto[p, e] = std::pair(c.begin(), c.end())` :)

Comment: @pm100 That is not how questions work here. Trying something might tell you what a particular compiler allows, not what the language allows.

Comment: @Raedwald you asked if it would be too confusing for a compiler. If you tried it yourself you might find that your compiler is not confused.

Comment: @pm100 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/170084 My question is not a no-effort noob "debug me" or "do my homework" question, but a question about how two language facilities are permitted to interact.

Comment: @Raedwald 100% agree, an experiment with a particular compiler proves nothing. I was just asking if he tried it. He might have said - well it worked on gcc xxx, but vs yyy barfed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can initialize them that way as long as they are of the same type (which they are in your example).

Comment: Declaring unrelated entities in the same line will indeed adversely impact readability. But declaring *closely related* entities in a single declaration (and even in one line) should be prefectly fine. (E.g. "begin" and "end" iterators.) I'd say that it even *improves* readability. Structured binding declaration in C++17 are actually step in that direction, as are many other language features. (Not my downvote, BTW)

Comment: Ill-advised recommendation turned +1 into -1. `auto b = v.begin(), e = v.end()` is an idiomatic way.

Comment: Fair points I took out my personal opinion as it got in the way of the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you use an auto deduced type where you have a comma operator to indicate initialization of two or more variables.

Yes.

> Or is the presence of two initialization too confusing for a compiler?

No, it is not. As long as the auto deduction does not result in inconsistent types declaring multiple variables in the same statement using `auto` is fine.

From the [C++11 Standard/7.1.6.4 auto specifier/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.spec.auto#3):

> ```
> auto x = 5;                 // OK: x has type int
> const auto *v = &x, u = 6;  // OK: v has type const int*, u has type const int
> ```

However, you may not use:

```
const auto *v = &x, u = 6.0;
```

and hope for the type of `v` to be deduced as `const int*` and the type of `u` to be deduced as `const double`.